# Search ELPA/MELPA Package repositories

Tags: search, package-repositories

I know searching for packages in the ELPA/MELPA repositories might be available within emacs itself, but I'm just wondering, can I do the search on the Internet as well? Just like I know I can search for packages on my Android phone, but I still prefer doing searches for them on the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search MELPA directly: https://melpa.org

The site also allows you to sort by downloads (popularity).

You can also search GNU ELPA from its website: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/

GNU ELPA does not appear to provide for sorting by popularity.

Comment: FWIW, as of relatively recently there's also the built-in NonGNU ELPA archive (which lacks a search field): https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/